# Propose an alias to multi-site as multisite

Tags: support, status-declined, synonym-request

There is a [Drupal Group](http://groups.drupal.org/multisite) called "multisite" and messages there use the non-hyphenated version of the tag.

And as long as we're on the subject. What is the difference between subsite and multisite anyway?

Answer (score 1):

Tag synonyms are created when there are two tags that are used with the same meaning.
In this case, there isn't another tag that is used with the same meaning of [multi-site](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/multi-site). There aren't also [questions tagged "drupal" and "multisite"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/multisite+drupal), on Stack Overflow; this means there aren't questions on Stack Overflow that could be migrated on Drupal Answers, and that would need to be retagged. If there were such questions, Stack Exchange would remove the not existing tag from the question, before to migrate it. That would be a reason for creating a tag synonym, but we are not in that situation.

Subsite is, e.g., groups.drupal.org, or api.drupal.org, for drupal.org. A multisite is a Drupal installation that runs for different domains, e.g. example.com, and example.org.